# Mongoose query returning wrong count for distinct values in collection

Tags: express, mongoose, distinct

I am writing a mongodb query to get the count of distinct data in a collection associated with other field.

Here is my query

```js
metricsJson.totalPatients = await AppointmentSchema.find({
                doctorId: doctorId,
            })
                .distinct('patientId')
                .count()
```

When I run the query I got the count as 3 but In my collection the answer should be 2.
When I printed the value with out count I got an array with 2 id's.
I am not sure what wrong am I doing.

I am using mongoose version 7
Here are the screenshots of the values
[image: Screen shot of json data with count 3]
[image: Screenshot of the console data with two values only in array]

I have tried searching in stack overflow but no luck I got some unrelated solutions. May be I didn't search properly. After debugging I got to know it only happened for one of the value and others are working fine.

I am expecting all three values to be present as same coming from the database

This is the sample document of appointment schema
[image: Sample Appointment Document]

Comment: Can you add sample documents for AppointmentSchema and the expected result to the question?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I have added a sample document and the expected result is unique user  (patient ) count assosiated with the doctor

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you